# When custom column deleted, internal name still exists

Tags: column, content-database, internal-name, custom-content-type

I have an app that pulls data from custom column by internal name. If I create the column and delete it, than create it again, SharePoint still has the internal name saved and then appends a 0 to the internal name, which breaks my app. So lets say the columns internal name was 'Test' when I created it, then I deleted it and immediately tried to recreate it. The columns internal name is now 'Test0'. Lets say I deleted it again and recreate it quickly. Now the columns internal name is 'Test1'. The columns internal name needs to be 'Test'. All the internal names from the previously created and deleted columns still exist in the db. How long do I have to wait for those to disappear? I have waited 12 hours and they are still there! I need the internal names to be right when I create the column for when I demo my app. Is there some way to delete a column and also delete its internal name from the db? Please help!!!

Comment: You have this tagged as [tag:custom-content-type], which leads me to the question - _where_ are you creating the column from?  From the Site Columns gallery directly, or from the content type definition page (where you manage what columns are in the content type - you have links there for `Add from existing site columns`, `Add from new site column` and `Column order`)?

Comment: It is a column for custom content type, so I either use 'Add from new site column' or I create it directly from column page, than add it to the content type. Either way the internal names from previous columns with the same name still exist somewhere on SharePoint, so when I create the new column, the internal name is incorrect. (Creating column 'ATest' would give internal name 'ATest0' if I previously created and deleted a column with that same name, or 'ATest1' if I had created/deleted a column with that same name twice.

Comment: The reason I ask is that if you are trying to "delete" columns from the Content Type definition page, that doesn't really delete the column from the site itself, it only deletes that association between the column and the content type.  If you go to Site Settings -> Site Columns, and are deleting the columns from there, that _should_ delete them permanently, so if that's what you are doing and you still are having that issue, I don't know what to tell you.  But if you are going Site Settings -> Site Content Types -> your content type, and deleting from there, I could see why you are running...

Comment: ...into the issue you are.  You need to go to Site Settings -> Site Columns to truly delete columns.

Comment: No I am deleting them entirely, i am sure. I am definitely deleting them from the site columns page, not just from the content type. I create a column in SharePoint, lets say I call it 'Test', than the internal name is 'Test'. Now if I delete that column and create one again with the same name, the internal name is now is 'Test0'. If I repeat that, the internal name would now be 'Test1'.

Comment: This is a problem because my app targets the internal name 'Test', it does not account for 0's or 1's being appended to it. I am pretty sure this is because the internal name hangs around in the database for a while for some reason after deleting that column. So do you know how long after I delete 'Test' column I need to wait before I can make another column called 'Test' with the internal name of' Test' (not'Test0' or 'Test1'). This had made my app appear to not work yesterday because I made all the columns, then deleted them so I could showcase the column creation for a demo.

Comment: I'm sorry, I don't know.  I've never heard of that happening before.

Answer (score 0):

For any one else experiencing this issue, I found a solution. It turns out the document library was the thing remembering the internal name of the column. When I deleted the column, remade it, and uploaded a document to a NEW document lib using the column, which had NOT previously used the deleted column, then the internal name of the api response was correct. So the solution is either to wait for a few days, use a new document library, or add code to spfx custom web part to account for possible columns with 0, 1, 2..ect appended to the internal name.

Comment: So wait - you created a new column at the site level, added it to a content type, then added that content type to a library... then deleted the column from the _site_ level?  And that's where you were running into your problem?  When recreating the _site_ column but adding it back to the library?

Comment: Sorry Dylan, been off for a while. You are correct. To repro this issue, create new column at site level, add to content type, add content type to document lib. Remove content type from doc lib, delete column at site level, repeat above process. Now the internal name of the column will be incorrect when using that doc lib, solution is to wait for loooong time or use a new doc lib

Comment: I still think doing it that way you might be ending up with a _copy_ of the field in the doc lib.  After you delete the content type from the doc lib and then delete the column from the _site_ level, go back to the _doc lib_ and see if the columns from the content type are still there (even though the content type itself is gone).